# Giving out bank information

Tags: united-states, banking, money-transfer

I asked a guy i know for one hundred dollars. He said send me your bank information so he could send it to me. Should i give it to him or use something else like paypal?

Comment: How, exactly, do you know him?

Comment: I know him through a friend

Comment: I'd definitely go the PayPal route if it's available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is someone you trust, for an amount of money that comes from a source you understand (i.e. not from some arabian prince), then you can provide him with your bank details. Those should be limited to bank id, account number and transit.

You should absolutely *never* under any circumstance share your PIN or online credentials such as your username, card number, password and secret questions. Apart from the obvious theft potential, this could void any theft warranty / insurance from your financial institution and leave you with significant financial losses.

Edit: Depending on your location and financial institutions, you may not even have to share bank details. For instance, there is a service in my area that allows for fund transfers through text or e-mail for a $1.00 fee.